# How to compare two rows from datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have to tables in the first table de user selected the rows  to add with a checkboxes in each row then presses a button add rows under the first table. However I do not want the rows that have already been added to be removed and added again. I only want to add the rows that haven't been added yet. Here is my code

```
    protected void GetSelectedRecords(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[10] { new DataColumn("Marca"), new DataColumn("Designacion"), new DataColumn("Tipo"),
                                                new DataColumn("Referencia"), new DataColumn("Plazo"),new DataColumn("nombre_proveedor"),
                                                new DataColumn("cantidad_requerida"),new DataColumn("cantidad_pedida"), new DataColumn("cantidad_entregada"),
                                                new DataColumn("precio_unitario")});
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPurchases.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    string brand = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblMarca") as Label).Text;
                    string designation = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblDesignacion") as Label).Text;
                    string type = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblType") as Label).Text;
                    string reference = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblReference") as Label).Text;
                    string paymentDeadLine = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblPaymentDeadline") as Label).Text;
                    string supplier = drSupplier.SelectedItem.Text; 
                    string requiredQuantity = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblrequiredQuantity") as Label).Text; 
                    string requestedQuantity = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblRequestedQuantity") as Label).Text;
                    string deliveredQuantity = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblDeliveredQuantity") as Label).Text;
                    string unitPrice = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lblUnitPrice") as Label).Text;

                    dt.Rows.Add(brand, designation, type, reference, paymentDeadLine, supplier, requestedQuantity, deliveredQuantity, deliveredQuantity, unitPrice);
                }
            }
        }
        gvPurchasesSelected.DataSource = dt;
        gvPurchasesSelected.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check that using Linq or doing a foreach or any iteration method you prefer over the gvPurchasesSelected.Rows before doing the dt.Rows.Add and check if the brand and designation and type are the same (or the fields that compose a unique identifier for the rows).

I would do something like this probably:

```
    if ( gvPurchasesSelected.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(row => row.type == type && 
                                             row.brand == brand && 
                                             row.designation == designation))
        continue;
    else
        dt.Rows.Add(....)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I try to add your code I get the following errors GridviewRowCollection does not contain a definition for 'Any'. And for row I get the following error 'row' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope I was able to fix row error by simply renaming it to rowSlected However i do not know how to fix the error I get for any

Comment: Ups, sorry about that, I forgot you need to cast becaus Rows is not IEnumerable. Add this before the Any and it should work: .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()

Comment: By adding the cast I get the following erreur DataGridViewRow could not be found here is the code that generates that erreur                                                                                        if (gvPurchasesSelected.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(rowSelected => row.type == type &&
                                        row.brand == brand &&
                                        row.designation == designation))

Comment: Mmmmm... I can´t replicate that error. Could you tell me the type of gvPurchasesSelected just to be sure. And careful with the Lamba function, you wrote rowSelected => and then you are using row instead of rowSelected, those have to match.

Comment: gvPurchasesSelected is a GridView and dt is a datatable

Comment: Ok, try changing DataGridViewRow for GridViewRow and see if that works. My tester project was actually a desktop app not web, so I was using DataGridView instead of GridView. Let me know if it works with that last change so I edit the answer and you can mark it as solved.

Comment: Almost, the cas works however now  type, brand, designation get the following error GridViewRow does not contain a definition for 'type' here is the new code                 if (gvPurchasesSelected.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Any(rowSelected => row.type == type &&
                                        row.brand == brand &&
                                        row.designation == designation))

Comment: Because you didnt change the rowSelected for row. Look a couple of comments above I said in the arrow function the first variable has to match what you use to the right of the arrow. It should be like this: if (gvPurchasesSelected.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Any(rowSelected => rowSelected .type == type && rowSelected .brand == brand && rowSelected .designation == designation))

Comment: The reason I used rowselected is when I use row I get the following error for row I get the following error 'row' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope as I have said in previous comment.